# For loop not being called in query function

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am calling the following function in the viewDidLoad of my collection view controller. I am trying to retrieve a value from the User class of my parse server. My problem is that the for loop is not being called which is not allowing the string value to be retrieved from the column and stored in the array.

```
func loaduuid(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")

    query.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: guestname.last!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("no error")

            for object in objects!{

                // add found data to arrays

                self.newuuid.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
                print("uuid added")

            }
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

Why is my for loop not being called and how can I fix this?

Comment: If the for loop `for object in objects!` is not executed, this would imply that the `objects` array is empty. This would be, as Paulw says, because no uuid was the same as `guestname.last`. But why guess? You have a wonderful debugger. _Debug!_ Step through the code, so you can see the path of code execution and what the value of variables like `objects` actually is. Look to see what the code does and why. Solve your own problem.

Comment: As Matt says, debug, but my guess is that there were no matches. It would be odd for a column names "UUID" to contain a last name

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `print(objects!.count)` to see if the array of PFObjects is empty, that might be why is not iterating through the array. If it prints 0, it means that your query is not finding any results on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in you have every information of his row from _User class in local device, you can access it with

```
let uuid = PFUser.currentUser()!["uuid"] as! String
```

or if there are some updated values in _User row you can use

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock...
```